# How to change the corner positions of UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uikit

I want to show a bellow image using UIImageView.

[image]

is it possible to show by UIImageView or any other way we can show it.

Please help me.

Comment: Why you need to change the corner position? Can you explain a bit more Ram?

Comment: dont get it at all sorry.. do you want to do a 3d transform like inPhotoshop

Comment: edit your quest. plz write exact wt u want :)

Comment: I want to construct a house and need to apply roof and siding etc.. images to that house.

Answer (score 0):

You need following type of design from your designer :

[image]

In above image. White part inside the red box will be transparent. And then you can set this image to `UIImageView`